# How do i load a local variable inside a module in Terraform?

Tags: variables, terraform

I have a locals.tf file with:

```
locals {
  labels = {
    mockup  = "duration is set 555"
  }
}
```

And a module called "TEST" where i define a GCP bucket resource:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "my_bucket_2" {
    ...
    labels = var.labels_bucket
}
```

I also have a variables.tf file inside the TEST module:

```
variable "labels_bucket" {}
```

Inside the main.tf file i loaded the module like this:

```
module "test" {
  source = "./TEST"
  labels_bucket = local.labels
}
```

I expected the variable to get the value of the local one, instead i get this error inside the module:

> googleapi: Error 400: Invalid argument, invalid

How do i map these values?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you accepted an answer that is unrelated with "How do i load a local variable inside a module in Terraform?" can you change the title of your question ? It's important because people that want to know how to load a local variable inside a module in Terraform are dirrected to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, Because it's issue with value of the map. Nothing to do with terraform.[image: gcs label format]

Comment: Thank you, so obvious now that you showed me. I was so deep in this that i overlooked it.